# LINQ: Select DateTime with unique value of minutes

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datetime

I have a list of DateTime objects.

I want select objects with unique values of minutes into separate list using LINQ.

I think that first step is use GroupBy() to group items by minutes. After that select original values using Distinct(). I works with VB.NET. But I do not know VB.NET syntax to write this query, and all examples that I've found are written on C#.

May anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: You can try using https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgRgNAJiDUAfAAgBgATIIwG4BQamWAdADICWAdgI76HYAsdGAsuQMYBOA9gM7cAzYMQDCAZQAWAQ04AHfAQDMmAEzoR6AN550u9Dr3JlIgBQBKA7u16b+mwF9Ldw8qrB0ADy0BzAKbAce3QAXnQAVnx7IA== and insert the C# code you want, then set output to visual basic.

Comment: This looks like a job for ToLookup.

Comment: @DavidB I checked it, and it good idea. It's works. But slower than Daniel's answer about using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following...

```
Dim list As New List(Of DateTime)

list.Add(Now)
list.Add(New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 6, 3))
list.Add(New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 6, 3))
list.Add(New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7))
list.Add(New DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7))

Dim q = list.GroupBy(Function(d) d.Second).SelectMany(Function(g) g.Take(1)).ToList()
'Outputs a list of 3 dates
'Current Date
'1/1/2001 05:06:03
'1/1/2001 05:06:03
```

Comment: Just a small thing - it's probably better to do `.SelectMany(Function(g) g.Take(1))` rather than `.Select(Function(g) g.First())`. It's easy to create a situation where `.First()` can break.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, it's exactly what I want! I just set types strict in anonimous methods.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Enigmativity. I've amended the answer.

Comment: It should also be added that if the current Date/Time has 3 or 7 seconds, only two items will appear in the list.